# Xamarin Community Toolkit MediaElement doesn't display videos

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created this ContentPage to display a video:

```xml
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            
            <xct:MediaElement 
                        Source="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5d93/a1eab4bf-3288-4faf-81c4-294402a85d93/XamarinShow_mid.mp4"
                        ShowsPlaybackControls="True" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

But the result is a blank page without any content.

Comment: Maybe set Width and Height

Comment: Did this fox the problem?  It would be polite and helpful to others to acknowledge if it was

Comment: yes, adding width and height solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I added HeightRequest and WidthRequest and It's worked fine